# Unable to resolve "react-navigation" from "node_modules\react-navigation-stack\lib\module\navigators\createStackNavigator.js"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
Unable to resolve "react-navigation" from "node_modules\react-navigation- 
stack\lib\module\navigators\createStackNavigator.js".
```

package.json:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of App.js

```js
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update:
For latest version (Version: **5.x**)
use

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```